# Action bar showing two action bar

Tags: android

My `ActionBar` is not working properly . See this: 
[image]

`AndroidManifest.xml` code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.xyz">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How to remove the lower action bar which is not displaying activity name ?

Comment: Show me your xml layout

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I deleted this line.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

So, once I added it, it started working nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Hide the second one in styles.xml by changing colors.

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It can work for that particular activity . But i want to remove that action bar (with no activity name ) otherwise my textview inside that activity gets shifted